# Secure onion router setup

Tags: firewalls, tor, router

I would like to setup a Raspberry Pi as an onion router, but I have some questions about it.

At home I am using a Fritz!Box to connect to the outer world (to the net of my ISP). Would it make any sense to put the RasPi behind such an router when it runs as onion router.

(I would like to still be able to access this obscure outer world outside the Tor network with other devices - depending on the sense and security at the same time or at different times but without time consuming reconfigurations.)

How should I setup certain firewalls (in general and for this certain case)? (Firewalls on terminal devices as well as on the routers)

@Edit:
I am not sure if it is a good idea to change the question - the question shows that I have a certain lack of expertise in the topic. I saw/googled other questions concerning TOR that had negative votes but showed that I am not the only one with certain problems to understand the context. I think it is important to keep this questions for people who are new to the topic as I am. (For example I wasn't sure in which way a TOR Router and a relay node correlate and also about the exact rules I am able to apply - can an relay node which I use as entry node prohibit other users to exit the TOR network. Would it be suspicious when I am the only user accessing and exiting the network over this node? I mean I know how Mixes/Mix-Networks work but I have several knowledge gaps concerning TOR and as I am not in a community where I can ask people in person I will sometimes ask imprecise questions.

I basically ask these questions to fill my knowledge gaps and to understand which risks are there and how to prevent them. Just knowing about the algebra and certain security/authorization/authentication/encryption/signing/anonymization-protocols and even formal methods to find vulnerabilities in protocols doesn't really help in practice.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with the edit, it is still too broad. You need to focus on a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind from a network security stand point is ensuring you have a solid DMZ in place. The DMZ is the ideal network location for you to separate your internal home devices from your devices that you would like to speak directly to the internet.

Your network stack would look something like this:

1. ISP
2. MODEM
3. Firewall/Router (Or firewall then router if using separate equipment)
4. DMZ
5. Firewall (same options as number 3)
6. Your internal network

By using this kind of set up, you reduce your risk of internal impact to your private network devices which should NOT serve information to the internet. Even if your DMZ is compromised, attackers would then need to traverse an additional firewall and router system to get to any of your personal data.

Now, you can technically use the Fritz!Box to setup a DMZ and have a single router configuration. This would be a cheaper alternate to setting up two different routers and having to configure your network hops from router to router. Instructions are below:

https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7581/knowledge-base/publication/show/131_Setting-up-a-DMZ-with-the-FRITZ-Box/

My only concern is that most consumer grade routers today fail security tests regularly, and I'm not sure that you'd want one single point of compromise for your entire network. Then again, I like tinfoil hats a lot and they tend to keep me employed!

Finally, opening yourself up to Tor traffic can be exciting, but it also invites scrutiny from governments that you may not want. You are also allowing illicit traffic to flow through your network, even if that's something you're otherwise against. There are many ethical issues to sort through as you become a member of the Tor relay. That's not to say all people who work on Tor are bad (in fact there are many legitimate uses), but it is still something to consider.

Comment: I fail to see what ethical issues you are talking about. There may be potential legal issues if you run an exit relay if that's what you are referring to, but I see no indication that OP is trying to do that.

Comment: Setting up a Tor router and contributing to the distribution of Tor traffic means that some of that traffic will be for illicit purposes. Though this is likely outside the intent of the OP, it still a consideration none the less.

Comment: Well so is working at a store that sells hammers. Or even food.

Comment: Not sure that's a great comparison, also doesn't negate the fact that it should be a posted concern when you chose to host that kind of connection to the world. I'm sure the OP has considered their options and they've chosen this path; but I wouldn't want future viewers to take this without having thought it through themselves.